# XPath expression to select unique nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm working on a project where I have to transform some XML input to some XML output, and for this I'm using XSLT version 1.

The input XML files I'm working on are *huge* like 10k+ lines, but I've spent the better part of an hour boiling it down to the following code snippet, which caputures the problem.

This is the input XML

```
<QueryInput >
  <Subject>
    <Content>
      <MunicipalityCode>0217</MunicipalityCode>
    </Content>
  </Subject>
  <QueryResultStep>
    <Multistep>
      <IterationResponse>
        <QueryResult>
          <Kommune>0217</Kommune>
        </QueryResult>
      </IterationResponse>
      <IterationResponse>
        <QueryResult>
          <Kommune>0217</Kommune>
        </QueryResult>
      </IterationResponse>
      <IterationResponse>
        <QueryResult>
          <Kommune>0223</Kommune>
        </QueryResult>
      </IterationResponse>
      <IterationResponse>
        <QueryResult>
          <Kommune>0223</Kommune>
        </QueryResult>
      </IterationResponse>
    </Multistep>
  </QueryResultStep>
</QueryInput>
```

The output XML should contain each "Kommune" once, removing duplicates. For this I made the following XSLT code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi xsd">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <QueryResult>
      <xsl:variable name="something">
        <KommuneCollection>
          <xsl:for-each select="QueryInput/QueryResultStep/Multistep/IterationResponse/QueryResult/Kommune[not(.=preceding::*)]">
            <NewKommune>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </NewKommune>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </KommuneCollection>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$something"/>
    </QueryResult>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Which produces the following (almost correct) output:

```
<KommuneCollection>
    <NewKommune>0223</NewKommune>
</KommuneCollection>
```

But should produce

```
<KommuneCollection>
    <NewKommune>0217</NewKommune>
    <NewKommune>0223</NewKommune>
</KommuneCollection>
```

If I remove the `<MunicipalityCode>0217</MunicipalityCode>` in the input XML, all of a sudden it works - but i *really* dont understand why. Not why it's happening, and I dont know how to address this issue either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The issue can easily be replicated by copying the input XML into Notepad++, installing the XPathenizer tool, show the window and enter this XPath expression `QueryInput/QueryResultStep/Multistep/IterationResponse/QueryResult/Kommune[not(.=preceding::*)]`, and executing the expression. The results can then be seen on teh right side. I suspect the problem to be with the XPath expression used in the `for-each` tag in the XSLT.

Comment: See the standard article on XSLT 1.0 grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate would have worked, but was failing to include "217" because the `/QueryInput/Subject/Content/MunicipalityCode` happened to have the value "217".

If you adjust your predicate filter to match for preceding `Kommune` elements instead of any preceding element, then it will produce the desired results:

```
[not(.=preceding::Kommune)]
```

However, it isn't very efficient. If your file is huge, then using a `xsl:key()` and the [meunchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) will be more performant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi xsd">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="Kommune" match="Kommune" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">     
        <QueryResult>
            <xsl:variable name="something">
                <KommuneCollection>
                    <xsl:for-each 
                          select="QueryInput/QueryResultStep/Multistep/
                                    IterationResponse/QueryResult/
                                    Kommune[generate-id(.) = 
                                            generate-id(key('Kommune',.)[1])]">
                        <NewKommune>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </NewKommune>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </KommuneCollection>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$something"/>
        </QueryResult>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 2):

As **michael.hor257k** says, Muenchian's grouping will be helpful for you(dealing with large files). But, following will be the correct version of your current try:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <QueryResult>
        <KommuneCollection>
            <xsl:for-each select="QueryInput/QueryResultStep/Multistep/IterationResponse/QueryResult/Kommune[not(. = preceding::QueryResult/Kommune )]">
                <NewKommune>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </NewKommune>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </KommuneCollection>
    </QueryResult>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Note**: This way is less efficient. You will feel the difference when you use Muenchian's grouping.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the `[not(.=preceding::*)]` expression select *all* preceding nodes - I would have thought it only took the preceeding nodes from it's parent. Thanks alot for your answer - helped me gain a little more insight in XPath! PS: I'm going to look into this Muenchian's grouping method. Thanks again.

Comment: To select preceding nodes, we have preceding-sibling axis. To correct your statement, `*` matches only elment nodes(not all nodes).